# Согласование по роду и числу слова "осталось", стоящего перед числительным

Tags: согласование, глаголы, род, число

Как правильно согласовать по роду и числу слово "*осталось*", если оно стоит перед числительным времени? Зависит ли это от порядка числительного? Так правильно?

До открытия **остался** один час и десять минут.
До открытия **остался** один час.
До открытия **осталось** два часа и десять минут.

До открытия **остался** двадцать один час и десять минут.
До открытия **остался** двадцать один час.
До открытия **осталось** двадцать два часа.

До открытия **осталась** одна минута и десять секунд.
До открытия **осталось** две минуты.

До открытия **осталось** три секунды.

Comment: Слово осталось, не надо склонять. Это глагол. Вы, вероятно, говорите о согласовании по роду и числу.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения за ошибку. Название темы и описание поправил.